# Use of dialect tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I added [south-korean](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-korean) and [north-korean](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-korean) to [What, if any, are the primary differences between Korean as spoken in the North and that spoken in the South?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/q/5/14) since they seemed relevant.

However, the former tag was immediately used on this question: [What are the differences between 는 / 은 and 가 / 이?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6/14)  However, that question doesn't seem to indicate in any other way that answers should be SK-specific, and it's probably not useful to exclude any information relevant to other dialects.  I suspect that the tag was used in lieu of simply [korean](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean) since that does not exist, and the asker is unaware that such a tag would not be useful.

So are these two tags useful, or just confusing?  I foresee a lot of similar misuse, but I think they are still useful categories.

Comment: It's an unavoidable question, so thanks for stating it this fast. Misuse of both tags is imminent and we should get a policy about that as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the *vast* majority of questions will be specific to South-Korean by default, and thus having explicit tags for both South and North Korean would be unnecessary.

Maybe an explicit tag for North Korean is okay, but I think we should just assume that unless specified, *any* general question is about the South Korean Standard Dialect / 표준어.

Short Version: A "North Korean" tag may be justifiable, but a "South Korean" tag is almost certainly redundant.

Comment: I don't disagree, but my question isn't really about what we should assume implicitly.

Comment: @MatthewRead, I guess I'm saying that the `South Korean` tag would be redundant, but keeping the `North Korean` tag may be justifiable.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm oh whoops, it is. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score -2):

I think just using the [dialects](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialects) tag would suffice.

Perhaps with [north-korean](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-korean) and/or [south-korean](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-korean) as synonyms, if there is a need for having those explicitly present in the tag system.

Comment: Adding them as synonyms will allow the problem I outlined to remain, while providing no benefits regarding categorization.

Comment: I believed that the tag synonyms automatically was converted into the base tag by the SE system. If that is not the case, I see your point, but am not sure if I agree.

Comment: Reworded slightly, as the synonym part was not the main exploratory part of my answer. My main question is: would using ‘dialects’ suffice?

Comment: It's worth noting that using a generic [tag:dialects] for this purpose is far too broad because there are far more regional dialects than just North/South Korean. Busan, Jeju, and other areas also have their own distinct dialects (which are often not entirely mutually-intelligible).